# getting error 'TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not object' when using react-leaflet-markercluster

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I want to make cluster of markers, but getting this error msg `TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not object` after importing react-leaflet-markercluster

i had deleted my `node_modules` folder and re-installed it, then updated it but still, there is the error

````
import React from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import MarkerClusterGroup from 'react-leaflet-markercluster';
import 'react-leaflet-markercluster/dist/styles.min.css';
import './style/dashboard.css';
import data from './../data/demo_data.json';

var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl:'https://gkv.com/wp-content/uploads/leaflet-maps-marker-icons/map_marker-red.png',
    iconSize:[25, 41],
    iconAnchor:[12.5, 41],
    popupAnchor:[0, -41],
    shadowSize: [68, 95],
    shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
})
export default class Dashboard extends React.Component{
    state = {
        lat: 22,
        lng: 92,
        zoom: 7,
    }
    render() {
        const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng]
        return (
          <Map className="map" center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
            <TileLayer
            attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            {data.map(item=>
                <Marker
                icon={myIcon} 
                position={[item.Latitude, item.Longitude]}
                >
                    <Popup>
                        'Hello'
                    </Popup>
                </Marker>
            )}
          </Map>
        )
    }
}```
````

Comment: And where does that error trigger? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: @IvanSanchez i am not allowed to upload an image yet, that's why
```inherits
C:/Users/Arafat Ahmed/projects/robiMap/robimap/node_modules/react-leaflet-markercluster/dist/react-leaflet-markercluster.min.js:43
  40 | }
  41 | 
  42 | function _inherits(e, r) {
> 43 |   if ("function" != typeof r && null !== r) throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof r);
  44 |   e.prototype = Object.create(r && r.prototype, {
  45 |     constructor: {
  46 |       value: e,```